# What kind of date format is this flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

could you please help me with the data which comes from API. It's a date-time data : "2022-03-30T18:56:17.33Z"

What is this data format and how can I turn it into a readable thing

Comment: What do you mean readable data? You can parse it to a `DateTime`. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html

Comment: Such as 03/03/2022 17:30

Comment: It's called ISO 8601 format. `DateTime` can parse it directly without the need for `intl` https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the `DateFormat` from `intl` :

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  print(
    DateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm").format(
      DateTime.parse("2022-03-30T18:56:17.33Z"),
    ),
  );
}
```

The above prints :
`30/03/2022 06:56`